# Rational approximations for $\pi$ using Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: approximation, fibonacci-numbers, rational-numbers, big-list, pi

It is (well?) known that
$$\frac{\pi} 4 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \arctan \left ( \frac1{F_{2k+1}} \right )$$
Where $F_k$ denotes the $k$-th Fibonacci number. However, any truncation of this sum is irrational!

> I am wondering what good *rational* approximations for $\pi$ are known which use the Fibonacci numbers.

**Motivation:** I can't find any! Not even on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80).

**I am not asking for** trivial such approximations, meaning nothing that simply abuses the fact that $F_1 = F_2 = 1$ or $a/a =1$. For example, though $355/113$ is a known good approximation for $\pi$, I don't think $355F_1 / 133$ is any more interesting, nor is $5*355 / (F_5*113)$.

**I am not asking for** approximations which are obtained using the fact that any integer may be written as a sum of Fibonacci numbers.

I think the following is neat, though not extremely accurate:
$$\frac{F_{15}F_{16}+1}{120F_{17}} = 3.1416\dots$$
I found this by accident earlier today, which is what made me wonder what other rational approximations for $\pi$ were known which used the Fibonacci numbers. To keep this question focused, I also say that I *prefer* approximations which exclusively use integers/Fibonacci numbers, as opposed to using terms from other rational sequences.

> I am particularly interested in rational sequences $\{ x_n \}$ which converge to $ \pi$ whose terms are defined using Fibonacci numbers, though I'm not sure if there are any (known). The fact that $ \frac{F_{n}}{F_{n-1}} \to \varphi$ might be useful.

Comment: Your question needs to be more precise. As it is stated, any rational approximation of $\pi$ works. Indeed, pick your favourite approximation, and write both the denominator and numerator as a sum of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: How much do you know about the theory of Diophantine approximation? Do you know about continued fraction representations?

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Just thought of one. Let
$$x_n = \frac{F_{n-1}^3}{F_{n}^3}.$$
Now, let
$$X_n = \frac{3327}{250}x_n.$$
$X_n$ gives a fairly accurate approximation of $\pi$, though it does not converge to $\pi$.

**Edit 1:** $X_{30} = 3.14159264\dots$, off in the eighth decimal place. Not a bad approximation!

**Edit 2:** I came up with this based on the fact that $\frac{\pi}{\varphi^3}(\frac{1000}{1109})=12$. However, about a second after posting this, and as user TonyK points out, I realized this is not true. However, this still produces quite a good (*not arbitrarily precise*) approximation for $\pi$. Not sure where $3327/250$ comes from.

Comment: That can't be right $-$ $x_n$ tends to $\varphi^3$, and $\pi/\varphi^3$ is irrational (because $\pi$ is transcendental and $\varphi$ is algebraic). What made you think it was true?

Comment: @TonyK edited answer accordingly.

Comment: $X_n$ certainly doesn't get arbitrarily close to $\pi$. If it did, $\frac{3327}{250}$ would be irrational. Which it isn't.

Comment: Also, $\frac{\pi}{\varphi^3}(\frac{1000}{1109})$ is less than $1$.

Comment: @TonyK Yes, I am not sure where I read otherwise.

Comment: You're putting in a lot of arbitrary information here (3327/250, as well your choice of expression involving $F_n$'s) so it's not surprising that you can get several digits of accuracy.

Comment: @JairTaylor yes; what I am confused about is that I got that fraction from an equation that was (very) incorrect, yet treating it as if it were correct gave me an accurate approximation with my sequence. I am wondering if this is a coincidence.

Comment: Just look at your expression for $X_n$. The fraction is greater than $12$, and $x_n$ tends to $\varphi^3$, which is greater than $4$. So how on earth can their product tend to $\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \,\frac{\left(F_{n-1}\right){}^3}{\left(F_n\right){}^3}=\sqrt 5-2$$ your constant $k=\frac{3327}{250}$ is the rationalized value of $\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{5}-2}$.

A sequence of the $k$'s would be
$$\left\{\frac{40}{3},\frac{133}{10},\frac{173}{13},\frac{2635}{198},\frac{3327}{250}
  ,\frac{1104391}{82987},\frac{1360570}{102237},
   \frac{1390513}{104487},\frac{4178193}{313961},\frac{38997
   577}{2930386},\frac{211700657}{15907774},\frac{298052197}{22396468},\frac{937332
   361}{70433751},\frac{56537993857}{4248421528},\frac{7
   7159305799}{5797964050},\frac{79971302882}{6009265303},\frac{718804393577}{54012
   953976}\right\}$$

Computing $$\Delta_n= \log_{10} \left(\left|k_n\frac{ \left(F_{99}\right){}^3}{\left(F_{100}\right){}^3}-\pi
   \right|\right)$$ we should have the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \Delta_n \\
 1 & -2.22327 \\
 2 & -2.72387 \\
 3 & -4.13879 \\
 4 & -4.71971 \\
 5 & -8.04467 \\
 6 & -8.62783 \\
 7 & -9.67057 \\
 8 & -10.8348 \\
 9 & -12.6291 \\
 10 & -13.6623 \\
 11 & -14.7505 
\end{array}
\right)$$ For the last of the $k$'s given above and $n=100$ as used for the previous table, we should have
$$\color{red}{3.141592653589793238462}46$$

But, we are looping in circles !